# Perlin Noise generating only 0

Tags: java

I am working on a Perlin Noise generator for my video game in Java. The problem is that whenever I run my generator then the only output I get is 0. Since I am new to Perlin Noise I am not really sure what to try, so therefore I have not tried anything except for tweaking the numbers with no change.

Here is my perlin noise code:

```
package PerlinGen;
import java.util.*;

public class PerlinNoiseGenerator {
private Random random;
private int octaves, x, y;
private int[][][] heightMap;

public PerlinNoiseGenerator(int octaves, int x, int y, long seed){
    heightMap = new int[octaves][x][y];
    this.octaves = octaves;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    random = new Random(seed);
}

public int[][] generate(int ic){
    for(int co=1;co<=octaves;co++){
        for(int cx=0;x<x;x+=Math.pow(2, co)){
            for(int cy=0;y<y;y+=Math.pow(2, co)){
                square(co, cx, cy, (int) (cx + Math.pow(2, co) - 1), (int) (cy + Math.pow(2, co) - 1), random.nextInt(co));
            }
        }

        for(int ci=0;ci<ic;ci++){
            for(int cx=1;x<(x - 1);x++){
                for(int cy=1;y<(y - 1);y++){
                    heightMap[co][cx][cy] = (
                        heightMap[co][cx][cy] +
                        heightMap[co][cx + 1][cy] + 
                        heightMap[co][cx - 1][cy] + 
                        heightMap[co][cx][cy + 1] + 
                        heightMap[co][cx][cy - 1]
                    ) / 5;
                }
            }
        }   
    }

    int[][] perlinNoise = new int[x][y];
    for(int cx=1;x<(x - 1);x++){
        for(int cy=1;y<(y - 1);y++){
            perlinNoise[cx][cy] = 0;

            for(int co=1;co<=octaves;co++){
                perlinNoise[cx][cy] += heightMap[co][cx][cy];
            }
        }
    }

    return perlinNoise;
}

private void square(int o, int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey, int v){
    for(int x=sx;x<ex;x++){
        for(int y=sy;y<ey;y++){
            heightMap[o][x][y] = v;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps me :)!

Answer (score 0):

Many of your loops will not run at all since the condition is never true. For example this one

```
for(int cx=0;x<x;x+=Math.pow(2, co))
```

will not run since `x` is never smaller than `x`.

Another example is this one

```
for(int cx=1;x<(x - 1);x++)
```

The condition `x<(x - 1)` is only true if x is the smallest possible integer (since `x-1` will overflow to a positive number).